# asp.net mvc3, facebook api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

how I can retrieve the information from my friends facebook,

I will retrieve this information: location, number of friends of my friends, description, picture, name,

```
var fbClient = new FacebookSdkClient(identity.Token.Token);
dynamic myInfo = fbClient.Get("/me/friends?fields=id,name,friendlists,location,picture");
```

I apologize for my English,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use FQL

```
dynamic friends = fbClient.Get("fql", new { q = "select uid, name, first_name, last_name, current_location, pic from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())" });
```

Please note that you need the appropriate permissions.

I do not think you can get the list of your friends' friends.

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks I 'm using Facebook SDK, its give an error when writting your code

Comment: Are you using Facebook C# SDK? ([link](http://csharpsdk.org/)).... if so... your fbClient should be created using `code`var FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient("YOUR TOKEN");`code`

Comment: Yes I'm using Facebook SDK but FacebookClient doesn't existe in FbSDK,(i'm use FacebookSdkClient but doesn't work) thanks

Comment: I think you are not using the same SDK I am using.... because I cannot find FacebookSdkClient in mine. I am using http://csharpsdk.org/. Anyways... This tool might help you test your Graph API / FQL requests  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cpicture%2Clocation